# Add Firebase Remote Config to android SDK(.aar)

Tags: android, firebase-remote-config

I'm trying to add firebase remote to config to the SDK which i'm developing but when I run the SDK in a app it says `IllegalStateException` and throws this

> "Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process
>   com.example.xyz. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context)
>   first."

Where as i'm calling `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context)` in the SDK. Can I know if anyone has implemented `FirebaseRemoteConfig` in a SDK (i.e., .aar file).

Another error which is causing gradle from building the app :

```
Could not get unknown property 'LibraryVariants' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.
```

Here is my build.gradle file :

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
//Retrofit
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
//Okhttp3
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
//Wakelock
compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:wakeful:1.1.0'
//Google Play Services
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1'
//Android Job
compile 'com.evernote:android-job:1.1.7'
//Firebase
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.0.1'
}
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a class in your sdk with at least one static method, e.g. `MySdk.init(context)` which get a context as input and in this method, you call `Firebaseapp.initializeApp(context)`. Also you have to ask the users of your sdk to call `MySdk.init(context)` in the `Application` class of their code or in their `launcher activity` class.

Comment: I'm calling `Firebaseapp.initializeApp(context)` when my sdk is initialized but still facing the same issue and another thing is while adding firebase remote config dependency and adding google play services plugin I'm getting another error which is  **Could not get unknown property 'LibraryVariants' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension**

Comment: You are calling 'Firebaseapp.initializeApp(context)' when sdk is initialized, so you have a static method to in your sdk for initialization? and about your error, please post a complete screenshot to make it clear.

Comment: Kindly check the question again I have updated the question again.